# Connecting to MySQL database on remote server - Access denied encountered

Tags: mysql

I was trying to connect to `MySQL` database on a remote server from the command line.

```
mysql --host=<host name> --user=<username> --password=<password> <db name>
```

I have no issue with connecting to the db from the PHP source but I encountered this error while trying to connect from command line. I connected with exactly same username and password.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '<username>'@'<host IP address>' (using password: YES)
```

I am not sure which went wrong.

Comment: does your password have spaces?

Comment: Are you running mysql from the same machine that php runs on?  The user may have host restrictions.